# How can I make this code a Dropdown menu for responsive?

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive, hamburger-menu

The hamburger menu icon should be on the right side, and the image should be on the left site.

When we will click the menu to open, it should open a dropdown and inside it should be the logo home *About us* gallery contact.

```html
<div class="rectangle1">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="li1"><a href="home.html"><img class="img" src="YOGI Logo.svg" alt=""> </a></li>
        <li class="li2"><a class="a1" href="#home">Home</a></li>


        <li class="li3"><a class="a2" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>

        <li class="li4"><a class="a3" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>

        <li class="li5"><a class="a4" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

        <a class="Contact_Us" href="contact.html">
            <img class="Contact-us-img"src="Vector.svg" alt="">
           <span class="Contact-us-text">Contact Us</span>
          </a>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I just need to turn it into CSS.

I need it for [iPhone 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_14) Pro to be responsive to be a hamburger menu.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Neither you have written CSS nor your HTML is correct. This is Stack Overflow, used to clear doubts and your description sounds like a ChatGPT prompt. You should start using ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the modified CSS code to achieve the responsive hamburger menu:

**CSS (styles.css):**

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none; /* Hide the menu icon by default on larger screens */
}

.menu-toggle::before, .menu-toggle::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.menu li {
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* Media Query for Mobile Devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu {
        display: none; /* Hide the menu by default on small screens */
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #333;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu.active {
        display: flex; /* Show the menu when active */
    }

    .menu li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-toggle {
        display: block; /* Show the menu icon on small screens */
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Editing it to remove the text doesn't make it not ChatGPT

Comment: That is not true

Comment: Re *"Here's the modified CSS code"*: None were provided in the question. Do you just ***blindly*** copy&paste to and from [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you: *[CSS @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php)*. As you can see in that tutorial, there is a way in CSS to check how wide the screen is.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

In this example, the background-color will be set to lightblue, when the width is smaller than 600 pixels. Using this rule, you can change your CSS accordingly.

You should definitely try to implement it yourself, and not just copy paste from the Internet. Go experiment, and have fun with CSS; that's the only way to learn it.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.